# Fragment with cardslib to fill the whole screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, cardslib

I tried making an app using [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android-2) tutorial (example 2). I created a navigation drawer activity.

My main fragment xml (added card):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:id="@+id/mainfragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/abovecards">





            <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView
                android:id="@+id/myList"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                card:list_card_layout_resourceID="@layout/list_card_thumbnail_layout"
                style="@style/list_card.thumbnail"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my main activity activity I added:

```
@Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            cardthingy();

        }

        public void cardthingy(){

            int listImages[] = new int[]{R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher1,
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher1, R.mipmap.ic_launcher};

            ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

            for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
                // Create a Card
                Card card = new Card(this.getActivity());
                // Create a CardHeader
                CardHeader header = new CardHeader(this.getActivity());
                // Add Header to card
                header.setTitle("Test: " + i);
                card.setTitle("Some text here");
                card.addCardHeader(header);

                CardThumbnail thumb = new CardThumbnail(this.getActivity());
                thumb.setDrawableResource(listImages[i]);
                card.addCardThumbnail(thumb);

                cards.add(card);
            }

            CardArrayAdapter mCardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), cards);

            CardListView listView = (CardListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myList);
            if (listView != null) {
                listView.setAdapter(mCardArrayAdapter);

                //this I tried from googling possible solutions
                FrameLayout mainy = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.container);
                mainy.setLayoutParams(new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                RelativeLayout fragy = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainfragment);
                fragy.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                ScrollView feed = (ScrollView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
                feed.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                LinearLayout rLGreen = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.abovecards);
                rLGreen.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                listView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            }



        }
```

The problem is that it is showing a scrollable screen that only fills up space of 1 card instead of the whole screen:
[image]
As you can see in my xml and java, I've tried some things to fix this, but unfortunately I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. The solution was pretty simple. The problem was fixed by removing the scrollview from the xml

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >
</ScrollView>
```

The card list view automatically becomes scrollable after a certain amount of items.

And the following lines weren't necessary any more:

```
            //this I tried from googling possible solutions
            FrameLayout mainy = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.container);
            mainy.setLayoutParams(new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            RelativeLayout fragy = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainfragment);
            fragy.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            ScrollView feed = (ScrollView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
            feed.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            LinearLayout rLGreen = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.abovecards);
            rLGreen.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            listView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: Yes. Never use a ListView inside a ScrollView in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
```

to

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
```

Comment: Haven't tested it yet. Will do it as soon as I get home :)